# How to configure a NestJs Jest test for a repository function

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs, ts-jest

My goal is to add some unit tests to functions that exist in a custom repository file within a nestjs project.

**Service:**

```
@Injectable()
export class TacoService {

  constructor(
    public readonly tacoRepository: TacoRepository,
    private readonly userRepository: UserRepository,
    public readonly bcdaRepository: BurritoRepository,
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => MakerService))
    private readonly makerService: MakerService,
    ...
  ) {}
...
}
```

**Repository:**

```
@Injectable()
export class TacoRepository {

constructor(
  @Inject(Topping.name) private readonly toppingRepository: typeof Topping,
  @Inject(Sauce.name) private readonly sauceRepository: typeof Sauce,
  ...
  ) {}

 public getTacoString(offset: number | undefined, limit: number | undefined) {
    return !isUndefined(offset) && !isUndefined(limit) ? `${limit} ${offset}` : '';
  }
...
}
```

**Test:**

```
describe('TacoRepository test suite', () => {
  let tacoService: TacoService;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [TacoService],
      exports: [TacoService],
    })
      .useMocker(token => {
        if (typeof token === 'function') {
            const mockMetadata = moduleMocker.getMetadata(token) as MockFunctionMetadata<any, any>;
            const Mock = moduleMocker.generateFromMetadata(mockMetadata);
            return new Mock();
        }
      })
      .compile();

    tacoService = module.get<TacoService>(TacoService);
  });

  describe('Get taco string tests', () => {
    let actual;

    it('should return an empty taco string when the limit and/or offset are undefined', () => {
      actual = tacoService.tacoRepository.getTacoString(undefined, undefined);
      expect(actual).toEqual('');
      actual = tacoService.tacoRepository.getTacoString(undefined, 10);
      expect(actual).toEqual('');
      actual = tacoService.tacoRepository.getTacoString(0, undefined);
      expect(actual).toEqual('');
    });
  });
});
```

When I execute the test, I always get a an actual value of "undefined", which is because the TacoRepository is mocked. But I cannot figure out how not to mock this repository and then mock the dependencies of the TacoRepository.

I've tried creating the test module using the TacoRepository instead of the TacoService, but that causes errors complaining "Nest can't resolve dependencies in the RootTestModule context". Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should be able to add `TacoRepository` to the `providers` array of the test module metadata Or if you're looking to test the `TacoRepository` directly you shouldn't need the `TacoService` in the first place

Answer (score 1):

At its very core, `Test.createTestingModule` creates a *standard* NestJS module using *standard* dependency injection functionality. This means that if you define a provider there (`Test.createTestingModule({ providers: [TacoService] })`), the Test module must be able to resolve ***all*** dependencies of that provider (in your example that would be all dependencies of the TacoService - i.e. TacoRepository, UserRepository, BurritoRepository & MakerService), as well as dependencies of dependencies, and so on - the whole dependency tree. If it can't do that, it will complain (as it does - "can't resolve dependencies...").

The way you employed the `useMocker` function ensured that *every single provider with a function-type token* (classes, essentially) was mocked (excluding TacoService itself, I believe). This way you ended up writing tests for mocks rather than your actual code.

Now, TacoRepository also has dependencies (toppingRepo, sauceRepo, etc.), but the injection tokens of these dependencies are (I presume) ***strings*** and not functions. If you mock the whole TacoRepository (which is the case in your code), you don't need to mock its dependencies anymore, so the code runs fine.

However, if you add TacoRepository to the providers array, its dependencies are not mocked (because their injection tokens are strings, whereas your `useMocker` only mocks function tokens), NestJS is not able to resolve them and throws an error when you run the test.

What's an injection token? That you'll have to research yourself. But I will say that when you write `@Inject(Topping.name)`, `Topping.name` acts as an injection token, and it's probably a string, right? So you need to define some provider for this token so that NestJS knows what to inject there.

So that's one way to fix the problem:

```js
beforeAll(async () => {
    const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
        providers: [
            TacoRepository,
            {
                provide: Topping.name,
                useValue: {} // Your mock implementation
            },
            {
                provide: Sauce.name,
                useValue: {} // Your mock implementation
            }
            // ... any other dependencies of TacoRepository must be mocked
        ],
        exports: [TacoRepository]
    })
        .compile();
});
```

Or you could supplement the `=== "function"` condition in `useMocker` with an `=== "string"` condition:

```js
useMocker(token => {
    if (typeof token === "function") {
        const mockMetadata = moduleMocker.getMetadata(token) as MockFunctionMetadata<any, any>;
        const Mock = moduleMocker.generateFromMetadata(mockMetadata);
        return new Mock();
    }

    if (typeof token === "string") {
        // mock string providers
    }
}).compile();
```

However, if you really wish to test the TacoRepository in isolation (mocking all of its dependencies), you'd be better off without using the Test module altogether. That is the very first example that you'll find in [NestJS's documentation for testing](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/testing#unit-testing).

```js
describe("TacoRepository test suite", () => {
    const toppingRepositoryMock = {}; // Create whatever mock you think is appropriate
    const sauceRepositoryMock = {}; // ... same
    const tacoRepository = new TacoRepository(toppingRepositoryMock, sauceRepositoryMock);

    describe("Get taco string tests", () => {
        let actual;

        it("should return an empty taco string when the limit and/or offset are undefined", () => {
            actual = tacoRepository.getTacoString(undefined, undefined);
            expect(actual).toEqual("");
            actual = tacoRepository.getTacoString(undefined, 10);
            expect(actual).toEqual("");
            actual = tacoRepository.getTacoString(0, undefined);
            expect(actual).toEqual("");
        });
    });
});
```

If you wish to mock everything *except* TacoRepository, you could try modifying your use of `useMocker` to ignore that particular token.

```js
beforeAll(async () => {
    const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
        providers: [TacoService],
        exports: [TacoService]
    })
        .useMocker(token => {
            // Note the additional condition
            if (typeof token === "function" && token !== TacoRepository) {
                // ... create your mock
            }
        })
        .compile();
});
```

Comment: OT I would be careful with writing very narrow tests, such as this one. Is the repository class really a "unit"? Perhaps the whole "Taco" system would be a better unit? If your tests are too narrow, you won't be able to refactor your code without breaking the tests. This tends to get frustrating and people sometimes stop writing tests because of that.

Comment: Thanks for answering this Avius, this is incredibly helpful feedback. I do think we are struggling to define the balance between how narrow our tests are and what we think the appropriate level of coverage is. This gives me a good place to start. Thanks again.